# I am having doubts on how checksum is calculated

Tags: checksum

Can you please calculate checksum value of this 010001010111 and write down the steps for me. It would help a lot.

I was told to split the data into equal bits and then instead of adding it I would check if the value is an odd or even number if it is even I write 0 and if it odd I write 1. Like for example;

0100
0101
0111
0110  (This is the ans I got)

Later I google searched some methods and the method I learnt differs from those methods.

Comment: There are lots of checksum algorithms, so which one are you using?

Comment: You seem to be describing a specific custom algorithm but it doesn't make sense. "split the data into equal bits" - a bit is a 0 or 1, the smallest unit that data can be split into, so what do you mean by _equal_ bits? Do you mean equal _groups_ of bits? How many groups should it be split into, or how big should a group be? Also, "if the value is an odd or even number" means only the last digit of each group is significant, which doesn't sound like a particularly good algorithm as it would ignore all the other bits. Please describe your algorithm in more detail.

Comment: sorry i meant to say groups of equal nibbles. 4 bits and 4 bits.